# Load XIB into View of another XIB

Tags: swift, uiview, xib, nib

I have an XIB file that has a CustomUserView (UIView with base class CustomUserView) that is blank and a UIButton. This has a controller, MyMainController. In the main controller method I have the code:

```
//Set up user info view
        customUserView  = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomUserViewXIB", owner:nil, options:nil) as NSArray)[0] as CustomUserView
```

I have tried this code in both the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear methods. Now the CustomUserViewXIB has some fields in it, that I would like to appear. However, I am only getting that blank CustomUserView and the button. Is there a way to do what I am trying to do, or will I have to add the CustomUserView as a subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to load another CustomUserView and configure it, of *course* you have to add it as a subview. Otherwise it's just something sitting there in your *code*. A view that isn't added as a subview to some view that's actually in the interface is, well, not in the interface.

Comment: So there is no way to load a nib from the bundle and set it as a pre-existing view in the parent nib then redraw from the bundle-loaded nib?

Comment: @steventnorris That way _is_ a way to do that. What are you look for that it doesn't supply? Is it that you wish you were using a view controller here? Then use an embedded container view controller. But you need to tell me what you think is wrong so I can help you. What you're proposing to do - load a nib, extract a top level view, and stuff it into the interface - is perfectly legal and very powerful.

Comment: I was just trying to eliminate the extra view. In this case, I'll have to either have a UIView in the parent XIB as a container view, add constraints to that, then add a subview to the container view. OR I could add the constraints and subview programmatically in the controller. I wanted to have the view in the parent XIB, then just load a XIB into that view. Avoids some extra steps.

Comment: I don't see any "extra view" in the story. I only see the one. You instantiate and use it. Every instance has to come from somewhere. This instance comes from loading a nib. Loading from a nib is just like making any other view. Whats the problem?

Comment: Of course, I am assuming there is some reason why this view is kept in a different nib like that. Like maybe you need more than one copy of it during the course of your app? If you only need the one copy, then why is it in a separate nib. Just put it in the main storyboard / xib as part of the view controller's view. In other words, you _can_ have a view from XIB and insert into a view that comes from another XIB, but you can also just have everything the one XIB to start with. It's up to you.

Comment: The parent XIB has a blank CustomUserView in it (we'll call it blankView). Another XIB has fields in it (we'll call it fieldsXIB). I load the parent XIB when I create my view controller. Then in the controller I call the code I outlined above, suing fieldsXIB and assigning blankView = (view loaded from fieldXIB), but the fields don't show. Is there a way to do this like I am explaining where the fields do show? A redraw?

Comment: All I can do is repeat the first part of my answer. You can "assigning blankView = (view loaded from fieldXIB)" but that just changes what the `blankView` variable refers to. It does nothing to your _interface_. - So, about these fields. I have two questions. (1) Why aren't they in the blank view to start with, so that it isn't blank? (2) If that's impossible, and if what is important is the fields, why don't you rip them out of the second view and put them into blank view, in code? That way, there's only one blank view and it is no longer blank.

Comment: I'm working with a designer who prefers using the XIBs where possible. This view is being used in several places throughout the app (user info shows up on order forms, profile, etc). Its easier just to create a custom view and pop it in where I need. If I can't redraw the blank view from the nib, I guess I'm just left with adding it as a subview programatically. I've done that and it works. I was just trying to pair down the layers a little.

Comment: Then what you proposed in your original question, and what I confirmed you must do, is what you must do: load it from its nib and add it to your interface with `addSubview` or similar. There is no other magical way.